# Using Munkres formulation of the Hopf Trace formula to finish a proof of the Lefschetz Fixed Point Theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups, fixed-point-theorems

I am very inexperienced with Algebraic Topology but I am trying to put together a proof for the Lefschetz Fixed Point Theorem, that I can understand, for a presentation in class.

I am following Prasolov's "Elements of Homology Theory" as closely as I can. And for the record, I am only meant to present this proof to the class, not create it myself. I just want to understand what is going on to the best of my ability, so I have rewritten some things to that end.

I will post what I have so far below but I am wondering if someone can help me finish off this proof using the Hopf Trace Lemma that I have in the beginning? And if anyone spots any mistakes or other ways that I might finish off the proof that would be simple enough for a very lost student to try and wrap his head around, that would be much appreciated.

---

Before getting to the proof of the theorem, we are going to need the following lemma.

Lemma (Hopf Trace):

Let $X$ be a finite simplicial complex and let $\phi:C_n(X)\to C_n(X)$ be a chain map. Then
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n\text{tr}\big(\phi:C_n(X)\to C_n(X)\big)=\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n\text{tr}\big(\phi_*:H_n\big(X;\mathbb{R}\big)\to H_n\big(X;\mathbb{R}\big)\big).
\end{align*}

Note: This formulation of the statement comes from Munkres (1984), ``Elements of Algebraic Topology'' and we have the used here the fact that any homology groups with real coefficients have the trivial torsion subgroup.

Theorem (Lefschetz Fixed-Point Theorem):

Let $X$ be a finite simplicial complex. If $f:X\to X$ is a map with Lefschetz number $\Lambda(f)\ne0$, then $f$ has a fixed point.

Proof

Suppose to the contrary that $f$ has no fixed points. Then, to prove the theorem, we must show that in fact $\Lambda(f)=0$.

Since $X$ is a finite simplicial complex, it is compact. To see this, note that since the simplicial complex $X$ is finite, it is constructed by finitely many simplices arranged in a finite manner. Since there are only finitely many simplices in $X$, we can construct an open cover of $X$ by taking the union of open neighborhoods of each vertex of each simplex. This open cover is finite because there are only finitely many vertices and simplices in $X$.

Now let's consider the distances between the points $x\in|X|$ and their images $f(x)$. Recall the assumption that $f$ has no fixed points, meaning that there does not exist an $x\in|X|$ such that $x=f(x)$. So, for each point $x\in|X|$, we may take an open ball centered at $x$ but excluding the point $f(x)$. The union of all of these open sets is a cover for $X$ and since $X$ is compact, we may take a finite subcover.

Next, since $X$ is finite, there must exist some subdivision $X'$ of $X$ such that the maximum diameter of any simplex in $X'$ is less than or equal to the minimum distance between the centers of the open sets in this finite subcover. Furthermore, we may in fact select this subdivision $X'$ to be such that for all $x\in|X|$: the distance between $x$ and $f(x)$ is larger than the maximum diameter of any simplex from $X'$.

Now let $X''$ be a further subdivision of $X'$ and let $\phi:X''\to X'$ be a simplicial approximation of $f$. Consider an arbitrary simplex $\Delta'' \subset X''$ and let $x''$ be any point within the interior of $\Delta''$. Then, the point $\phi(x'')$ belongs to the only simplex of $X'$ whose interior contains $f(x'')$; but recall that we've ensured the distance between $x''$ and $f(x'')$ is greater than the maximum diameter of any simplex in $X'$. Thus, since $X''$ is a subdivision of $X'$, the simplex in $X'$ containing both $f(x'')$ and $\phi(x'')$ must be disjoint from the simplex in $X''$ containing $x''$. Finally, since $x''\in\Delta''$ was arbitrary, we have that for any simplex $\Delta''\subset K'$, the sets $\Delta''$ and $\phi(\Delta'')$ are disjoint.

*** This is where I am not sure how to proceed to finish things off ***